# Black thread on wrist to ward off evil eye

Tags: nikah, evil-eye

My wife had wrapped my son wrist with black thread, according to her that it will keep him away from evil eye, I quoted her one of PBUH hadith from [isalmqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10543/ruling-on-amulets-and-hanging-them-up-do-amulets-ward-off-the-evil-eye-and-hasad-envy) but she said it is on amulets, Tawiz and not on a piece of thread that is there with intention of 4 quls so he doesn't get eye evil.

The problem is that every time I tell her something which her mother or anyone else in family is doing, she wanna prove me wrong or his brother try to be a scholar. How can I encounter this?

Comment: well, does she, her mother and brother at least believe the wife must obey the husband ?

Comment: @secretsquirrel I believe so but arguing has been very hard and I m given up it's a strange thing that she says that she has seen her parents do it so she will do it but if it is wrong then Allah punish me and not my mother but if it is written Allah become happy with me and my parents. For all I m concerned is not burdening my children or myself or her with Allah wrath but I have to argue with hadith

Answer (score 1):

Tell her that prophet never practiced such thing. Instead The Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) Said:

> "In his Khutbah the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to praise Allah as He
> deserves to be praised, then he would say: 'Whomsoever Allah (SWT)
> guides, none can lead him astray, and whomsoever Allah sends astray,
> none can guide. The truest of word is the Book of Allah and best of
> guidance is the guidance of Muhammad. The worst of things are those
> that are newly invented; every newly-invented thing is an innovation
> and every innovation is going astray, and every going astray is in the
> Fire.....'

Grade   : Sahih (Darussalam)
Reference    : Sunan an-Nasa'i 1578
In-book reference    : Book 19, Hadith 23
English translation  : Vol. 2, Book 19, Hadith 1579

There are many authentic Dua for protection against evil eye. This is one of them:

> It was narrated that Ibn ‘Abbas said: “The Prophet (ﷺ) used to seek
> refuge for Hasan and Husain and say: A’udhu bi kalimatil-lahil-
> tammati, min kulli shaitanin wa hammah, wa min kulli ‘aynin lammah (I
> seek refuge for you both in the Perfect Words of Allah, from every
> devil and every poisonous reptile, and from every evil eye).’ And he
> would say: ‘Thus Ibrahim used to seek refuge with Allah for Isma’il
> and Ishaq,’ or he said: ‘for Isma’il and Ya’qub.’”
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ سُلَيْمَانَ بْنِ هِشَامٍ الْبَغْدَادِيُّ،
> حَدَّثَنَا وَكِيعٌ، ح وَحَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ خَلاَّدٍ
> الْبَاهِلِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَامِرٍ، قَالاَ حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ،
> عَنْ مَنْصُورٍ، عَنْ مِنْهَالٍ، عَنْ سَعِيدِ بْنِ جُبَيْرٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ
> عَبَّاسٍ، قَالَ كَانَ النَّبِيُّ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ يُعَوِّذُ
> الْحَسَنَ وَالْحُسَيْنَ يَقُولُ ‏"‏ أَعُوذُ بِكَلِمَاتِ اللَّهِ
> التَّامَّةِ مِنْ كُلِّ شَيْطَانٍ وَهَامَّةٍ وَمِنْ كُلِّ عَيْنٍ
> لاَمَّةٍ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ وَكَانَ أَبُونَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ يَعُوِّذُ
> بِهَا إِسْمَاعِيلَ وَإِسْحَاقَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ أَوْ قَالَ ‏"‏ إِسْمَاعِيلَ
> وَيَعْقُوبَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَهَذَا حَدِيثُ وَكِيعٍ ‏.‏

Grade   : Sahih (Darussalam)
English reference    : Vol. 4, Book 31, Hadith 3525
Arabic reference     : Book 31, Hadith 3654

Also You can Recite Surat Al-Falaq and Surat An-Nas

> Abu Sa'id Al-Khudri (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The
> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to seek protection against the evil of
> jinn and the evil eyes till Surat Al-Falaq and Surat An-Nas were
> revealed. After they were revealed, he took to them for seeking
> Allah's protection and left everything besides them.

[At- Tirmidhi].
Sunnah.com reference: Book 8, Hadith 25

Arabic/English book reference    : Book 8, Hadith 1015