# Wife into bidah stuff and won’t say anything

Tags: bidah

My wife is into bidah stuff which she believes her mother use to do and she has been taught such way e.g. warding off evil eye by egg and throwing it away. Her mother knew I didn’t like it so she didn’t use to do it front of me but given my in laws habits they do it what they think is right and say we will cursed if we are wrong not you or kids.

Now and then my wife brother tell her to ward off evil eye by egg. My wife knows I dont like it and she is always silent instead of rectifying them and tell we don’t do that?

It have come to a point where I feel super annoyed. They also believe prophet Muhammad (PBUH) is noor of Allah and we don’t.

How can I make my wife stop it because it is like she won’t do it but still her family say things which annoy me or don’t know that I believe it as bidah.

Comment: Please note that we are not a supporting group as 1K+ user this shouldn't be new to you. In Islam you may have different options staring by gently informing her, showing evidences and asking her to stop. In worst case you should let her know that if these things are regarded as such that they may take her out of he fold of Islam you are no more her husband as she'd be regarded as disbeliever.

Comment: @Sassir what u mean by "not supporting group"

Comment: @localhost anything that has to do with opinions. Like everyone brings their own suggestions is what "supporting group" means. Check out this help article: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you already asked similar question [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/61518/35781).

You could show her evidence that doing innovation is serious sin in Islam. You can ask her for evidence for what they are doing. Most of these things are from culture, they follow this because their forefathers has practiced it. If that's the case then say to them that, "If your forefathers were non-Muslims then you would have been a non Muslim too, So reflect on Quran and hadith without following blindly" Maybe not the same wording but something like that you can say to them. And you would know what to say to them better.

**Also your wife should obey you.**

> And the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “It
> is not permissible for a woman to fast when her husband is present
> except with his permission, or to allow anyone in his house without
> his permission.”

*Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 4899.*

> Al-Albaani (may Allaah have mercy on him) said, commenting on this
> hadeeth: Since it is obligatory for a woman to obey her husband with
> regard to his satisfying his desire, it is more appropriate that it be
> obligatory for her to obey him in that which is more important than
> that, namely raising their children, guiding the family, and other
> rights and duties.

*From Adaab al-Zafaaf, p. 282*

Full Article [Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/43123/obeying-ones-husband-comes-before-obeying-ones-parents-and-siblings)